# I need to make another list of only that data next to which the check box is checked in VBA excel. What will be the code?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to list the data next to which checkbox is ticked. So I have around 190 check boxes and I need to make a new list in the same sheet having only the checked data. Previously I used Y or N option and this was the code for an idea.

Since I am being forced to add more details I have to write unnecessary words

```
Sub Button1_Click()

For I = 5 To 45
If (I = 20) Then

    I = I + 3
Else
If (I = 28) Then

    I = I + 3
End If
End If
If ((Worksheets("tests").Cells(I, 14) <> "Y") And (Worksheets("tests").Cells(I, 14) <> "N")) Then

    Worksheets("tests").Cells(250, 2) = Worksheets("tests").Cells(300, 2)
    TEMP = I
    Range(Cells(233, 1), Cells(233, 1)).Select
    GoTo 85
End If
Next I
For I = 83 To 126
Worksheets("tests").Cells(I, 3) = Worksheets("tests").Cells(3, 12)
Worksheets("tests").Cells(I, 2) = Worksheets("tests").Cells(I, 3)
Next I
For I = 133 To 172
Worksheets("tests").Cells(I, 3) = Worksheets("tests").Cells(3, 12)
Worksheets("tests").Cells(I, 2) = Worksheets("tests").Cells(I, 3)
Next I
J = 83
SUM1 = 0
For I = 5 To 19
If (Worksheets("tests").Cells(I, 14) = "Y") Then
    Worksheets("tests").Cells(J, 3) = Worksheets("tests").Cells(3, 2)
    I = 19
Else
    Worksheets("tests").Cells(J, 3) = Worksheets("tests").Cells(3, 12)
    SUM1 = SUM1 + 1
End If
Next I
If (SUM1 = 15) Then
GoTo 5
End If
J = J + 2
Sum = 0
For I = 5 To 19
If (Worksheets("tests").Cells(I, 14) = "Y") Then
    Worksheets("tests").Cells(J, 3) = Worksheets("tests").Cells(I, 2)
    Sum = Sum + 1
    Worksheets("tests").Cells(J, 2) = Sum
If (J = 126) Then
    J = J + 6
    GoTo 30
End If
30  
J = J + 1
End If
Next I
Sum = 0
J = J + 1
5 
SUM1 = 0
For I = 23 To 27
If (Worksheets("tests").Cells(I, 14) = "Y") Then
    Worksheets("tests").Cells(J, 3) = Worksheets("tests").Cells(21, 2)
    I = 27
Else
    Worksheets("tests").Cells(J, 3) = Worksheets("tests").Cells(3, 12)
    SUM1 = SUM1 + 1
End If
Next I
If (SUM1 = 5) Then
GoTo 10
End If
J = J + 2
For I = 23 To 27
If (Worksheets("tests").Cells(I, 14) = "Y") Then
    Worksheets("tests").Cells(J, 3) = Worksheets("tests").Cells(I, 2)
    Sum = Sum + 1
    Worksheets("tests").Cells(J, 2) = Sum
If (J = 126) Then
    J = J + 6
    GoTo 35
End If
35              
J = J + 1
Else
End If
Next I
Sum = 0
J = J + 1
10 
SUM1 = 0
For I = 31 To 45
If (Worksheets("tests").Cells(I, 14) = "Y") Then 
    Worksheets("tests").Cells(J, 3) = Worksheets("tests").Cells(29, 2)
    I = 45
Else
    Worksheets("tests").Cells(J, 3) = Worksheets("tests").Cells(3, 12)
    SUM1 = SUM1 + 1
End If
Next I
J = J + 2
For I = 31 To 45
If (Worksheets("tests").Cells(I, 14) = "Y") Then
    Worksheets("tests").Cells(J, 3) = Worksheets("tests").Cells(I, 2)
    Sum = Sum + 1
    Worksheets("tests").Cells(J, 2) = Sum
If (J = 126) Then
    J = J + 6
    GoTo 40
End If
40              
J = J + 1
Else
End If
Next I
Range(Cells(84, 1), Cells(84, 1)).Select
85       
Worksheets("tests").Cells(286, 15).Value = TEMP
250 
End Sub

Sub Button63_Click()
TEMP = Worksheets("tests").Cells(286, 15).Value
Range(Cells(TEMP, 14), Cells(TEMP, 14)).Select
End Sub

Sub MASTER()
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1)).Select
End Sub

Sub check()
Range(Cells(5, 14), Cells(5, 14)).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you already created the 190 checkboxes or is your code creating those checkboxes? It sounds like you want to concatenate the words from the checked boxes into a single comma-separated string?

Comment: not a single comma separated string, I want to make new list of those words

Comment: I have inserted the 190 checkboxes in the sheet. Now I need to write the code such that a new list is formed containing only those checkboxes that the user ticks.